# Calling Async Method in Net3.5 Deadlock

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-3.5, deadlock, configureawait

I am using .net3.5 and i have the following installed
[image]
This operation freezes. Can anyone tell me what i should be doing differently?

```
HttpClient Client;
    response =  await  Client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I had my project in Net4.0 before and the same line of code worked with the following libraries.

[image]

I needed to downgrade to Net3.5 and now my async call hangs with a response status `WaitingForActivation`.

I also just realised that the follwing works:

```
var response = await _client.GetAsync(Url, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Also returns a value in response.Results. Maybe the is something going on with SendAsync in the library?

After Further investigation i Realise that for the following

```
        var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://localhost:7000/connect/token"));
        var request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://localhost:7000/connect/token"))
        {
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "hq_api_access")
            })

        };

        var response1 = await client.SendAsync(request1).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var response2 = await client.SendAsync(request2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`request2` hangs. I am guessing its a bug in the library that happens when the request object is set with content. Is there another client i can use? for the .net 3.5 platform if there is no salvaging this one.

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**
As suggested in the comment below. I created an example to reprocuduce the problem. I am using Visual Studio 2015. Created a new .net3.5 console application.

I installed the following
 1. Install-Package Rackspace.HttpClient35 -Pre
 2. Install-Package TunnelVisionLabs.Threading -Pre

Below is how the main program looks like

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r = Demo();
            var a = r.Result;
        }

        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Demo()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
                new Uri("https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token"));
            var request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
                new Uri("https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token"))
            {
                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "api")
                })
            };

            var response1 = await client.SendAsync(request1).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var response2 = await client.SendAsync(request2).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return response1;
        }
    }
```

When i debug with breakpionts, response1 returns a response but response2 hangs.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `.Result` or `.Wait()` on a task **anywhere** in your program?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes But its null response.Result is Null. No i have not used .wait()

Comment: If you have an invocation of `Task.Result`, that's, most probably, where your dead lock is.

Comment: @PauloMorgado check my update. The deadlock only occurs when i set the content for HttpRequestMessage object. otherwise i get the response.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: It might be that `request1` is already completed when you invoke it's `Result` and `request2` isn't. The bottom line is that, if you're invoking `Result` you're setting yourself up for dead locks.

Comment: @svick Check my updates.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Well...when i debug request1 definately returns before continuing but request2 hanga forever. You can check out my  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example,

Comment: Tried that on [LINQPad 5.22.03](http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx#LINQPad5) and got "perfectly good" 400 responses from both. I haven't tested with .NET 3.5, though.